# Flutter / Dart - change Column to Row and display the result Realtime

Tags: flutter, dart, row

Flutter / Dart - I have a simple app but am new to programming, so struggling.

Currently, the setup is with all the TextInput boxes in a Column. I would like to change this to having them in a Row.  I assumed this would be easy by simply replacing the Word Column with Row on line 44. But it doesn't work and when I try to run it, the "errors_patch.dart" page opens (which I have never seen before) with a highlighted error on line 51 "int assertionStart, int assertionEnd, Object? message);".

How can I simply change from Column to Row?

How can I have the result show in real time rather than needing to click on the "Subtraction" button to get it?

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'Help with a meal....';
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(appTitle),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: const AddTwoNumbers(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTwoNumbers({super.key});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _AddTwoNumbersState createState() => _AddTwoNumbersState();
}

class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers> {
  TextEditingController num1controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num3controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num4controller = TextEditingController();
  String result = "0";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
            controller: num1controller,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Target Level',
              hintText: 'Enter First Number',
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          TextField(
            keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
            controller: num2controller,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Current Level',
              hintText: 'Enter Second Number',
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          TextField(
            keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
            controller: num3controller,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Current Meal carbs',
              hintText: 'Enter Third Number',
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          TextField(
            keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
            controller: num4controller,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Current Meal carbs 2',
              hintText: 'Enter Fourth Number',
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          Wrap(children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.purple),
              child: const Text("Subtraction"),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  double sum = double.parse(num1controller.text) -
                      double.parse(num2controller.text);
                  result = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
                });
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
              width: 20,
            ),
          ]),
          Text('Difference between Target Level and Current Level: $result'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'Help with a meal....';
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(appTitle),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: const AddTwoNumbers(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTwoNumbers({super.key});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _AddTwoNumbersState createState() => _AddTwoNumbersState();
}

class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers> {
  TextEditingController num1controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num3controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num4controller = TextEditingController();
  String result = "0";

  _calculate() {
    if (num1controller.text.isNotEmpty && num2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(num1controller.text) -
            double.parse(num2controller.text);
        result = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculate(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: num1controller,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Target Level',
                        hintText: 'Enter First Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculate(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: num2controller,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Current Level',
                        hintText: 'Enter Second Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculate(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: num3controller,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Current Meal carbs',
                        hintText: 'Enter Third Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculate(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: num4controller,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Current Meal carbs 2',
                        hintText: 'Enter Fourth Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Text(
                  'Difference between Target Level and Current Level: $result'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are switching to `Row` it doesn't know the width of the `TextField`s, so you need to wrap them with `Expanded` or `Flexible` widgets to make them take the space they need (or you can give them some fixed width if you wish), something like in the solution below. And the answer to the second question is also in the solution, you just call the calculate method on every `TextField` change.

```
class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTwoNumbers({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _AddTwoNumbersState createState() => _AddTwoNumbersState();
}

class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers> {
  TextEditingController num1controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num2controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num3controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num4controller = TextEditingController();
  String result = "0";

  _calculate() {
    setState(() {
      double sum =
          double.parse(num1controller.text) - double.parse(num2controller.text);
      result = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculate(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: num1controller,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Target Level',
                        hintText: 'Enter First Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculate(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: num2controller,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Current Level',
                        hintText: 'Enter Second Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculate(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: num3controller,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Current Meal carbs',
                        hintText: 'Enter Third Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) => _calculate(),
                      keyboardType:
                          const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                      controller: num4controller,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Current Meal carbs 2',
                        hintText: 'Enter Fourth Number',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Text(
                  'Difference between Target Level and Current Level: $result'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ante Bule, I'm currently working through your reply. However I have added the suggestions around "calculate method on every TextField change", but when I first start the app and the fields are all blank and I then start to add the first number, after entering the first digit I get the message "Exception has occurred. FormatException (FormatException: Invalid double )" - is this because it isn't allowing "null" or a blank field in the other text box and how can I get it to accept the one filed will be blank initially?

See image above for error - mkUa3.jpg

Comment: You are right, that happens if one of the fields is empty. You can add a simple `if` check before the calculation, something like: `if (num1controller.text.isNotEmpty && num2controller.text.isNotEmpty)`. In this case it will not calculate anything if one of the first two fields is empty.

Comment: Thanks, yes adding the line you suggested in this location worked! 

`code`
  _calculate() {
    if (num1controller.text.isNotEmpty && num2controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        double sum = double.parse(num1controller.text) -
            double.parse(num2controller.text);
        result = sum.toStringAsFixed(1);
`code`

Comment: The new image above is how the screen now looks with Ante Bule help, but I have a couple more questions. How do I put the real time result in a box like num1controller & num2controller are in, so that the top row has 3 boxes only: input / input / result.  I'd then like to put the num3controller & num4controller on a new row below. I have tried a few options but nothing works.

Comment: That's a totally new question unrelated to your initial question, so you should have created a brand new post (question) for that. But I'll just tell you here that instead of showing your result in the text below, like you currently do, you can place the result in the `TextField` on every `_calculation` method run, something like `resutlTextFieldController.text = resultOfCalculation;`.

Comment: Thank you for answering Ante Bule, I'll look at implementing your suggestion. I will post all new questions as a brand new post next time

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do what you're trying to achieve. For changing Column to Rows, you can use a container with a column as a child and rows as children in it. You can see the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout) for further assistance.

For your second question, you can use onChanged() callback or you can use TextEditingController to see the realtime changes in your TextField.

Comment: Thank you Ali Haider, I'm currently working through your reply